# Return JS function as string from server and execute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to time limit a socket.io connection time on a node.js server. I asked a previous question as to whether this was possible without causing a huge overhead on the server and or blocking the main thread if we had say 1000 concurrent socket connections in various rooms, through something like:

```
socket.on('connection', function(params){
   var maxTime = params.maxTime; 
   socket.join(params.roomId);
   setTimeout(function{
   socket.leave(params.roomId);
}, 180000)
});
```

The best case scenario would be handle this on the client side from a resources perspective but it isn't exactly secure to send the timeout/disconnection value as any lines of client side code that dealt with it could be easily manipulated and a knowing user could in effect prevent the disconnect event/functionality from being called.

Could I execute a function client-side sent as a string? Say:

```
setTimeout(function(){//disconnect},18000);
socket.emit('timeout_set', function(params){foo:bar});
```

Then handle appropriately on the server with a response knowing that the timeout has indeed been set:

```
socket.on('timeout_set', function(params){
socket.emit('proceed_with_stuff', {foo:bar});//includes critical info for proceeding
});
```

I'm thinking this depends on a few things:

1. Can you take a string from a server response and execute said string as JS?
2. Can a client still disrupt the setTimeout function without also triggering the socket.disconnect event?
3. Is this logic or anything similar possible?
4. Would the first scenario work on a node.js server given a number of concurrent connections?

Comment: Yes, that's certainly possible, using eval, if the string you're sending is valid javascript. though, i can't think of any situation where it would make sense to do this instead of having that logic client-side to begin with.

Comment: I'm mostly concerned with validating in some way that the connection will be terminated from the client side and can't be tampered with...

Comment: but, it's client-side, it can always be tampered with. you can't stop that. Adding a breakpoint on the callback to the message event would allow the user to modify the message (the function in string form) directly.

Comment: therefore I need to do this server side. What about the setTimeout server side approach? Is that a bad idea given the potential for concurrent connections and node's event loop?

Comment: You could reduce that possibility by instead storing the sockets creation timestamp on the socket, then periodically looping over open sockets and closing ones that have been open for more than x ms, thus avoiding having 1000 setTimeouts going. but, i don't know if that would actually be better.

Comment: That may work. Realistically if I have 1000 setTimeouts going I'm achieving some solid traction. Is there a rule of thumb for a processor or memory footprint for a setTimeout function? What about the event loop, they are considered async right?

Comment: Not that i'm aware of. setTimeout is considered async by most.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Function` constructor, see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function